# Parse fixed length text with attoparsec

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative, attoparsec

I need to parse fixed length fields with attoparsec but im now struggling with the compiler.
Im still a newbie, the code below is the closest solution I have:

```
> {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
> import Control.Applicative
> import Data.Text as T
> import Data.Attoparsec.Combinator
> import Data.Attoparsec.Text hiding (take)
> import Data.Char
> import Prelude hiding (take)
>
> type City = Text
> type Ready = Bool
> data CityReady = CR City Ready deriving Show
>
> input = T.unlines ["#London              1",
>                    "#Seoul               0",
>                    "#Tokyo               0",
>                    "#New York            1"]
>
> parseCityReady = many $ CR <$> cityParser <*> readyParser <* endOfLine
>
> cityParser = char '#' *>
>              takeTill isSpace <*
>              skipWhile isHorizontalSpace
>
>
> readyParser = char '1' *> pure True  <|> char '0' *> pure False
>
> main =
>   case parseOnly parseCityReady input of
>      Left err  -> print err
>      Right xs  -> mapM_ print xs
>
```

This is all great but it is only returning Cities without spaces.

```
CR "London" True
CR "Seoul" False
CR "Tokyo" False
```

I have tried using applicative to take 20 characters for the City text string

```
> cityParser = char '#' *>
>              take 20
```

and even `do syntax`

```
> cityParser = do char '#'
>                 city <- take 20
>                 return city
```

but both approaches fail to compile with this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `attoparsec-0.10.4.0:Data.Attoparsec.Internal.Types.Parser
                                Text b0'
            with actual type `Text -> Text'
In the return type of a call of `take'
Probable cause: `take' is applied to too few arguments
In the second argument of `(*>)', namely `take 20'
In the expression: char '#' *> take 20
```

What is causing the ghc to ask for `Text -> Text` when the `take` has a type of `Int -> Text -> Text`?

How do I solve it in both applicative and do-syntax?

Comment: You are hiding the version of `take` exported by `attoparsec`. Instead, you are using the `take` function exported by the `Text` module, which is not the one you want.

Comment: @sabauma indeed, I should have placed the `hiding` on Data.Text instead. Thanks!

Comment: @sabauma: if that's the correct answer, you should post it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, your problem is that you are hiding several versions of the `take`
function. In particular, you are hiding the `take` from `attoparsec` rather
than the `take` function from the `Text` module. All you should need to do is
change your imports like so

```
> import Control.Applicative
> import Data.Attoparsec.Combinator
> import Data.Attoparsec.Text
> import Data.Char
> import Data.Text as T hiding (take)
> import Prelude hiding (take)
```